# How to set specific time on date picker?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I am using date picker and selected datePicker mode as time. When I am loading the date picker it is showing current time.But I want to set default time always 5:00 PM.

I have tried the below way but it didn’t work for me.

```swift
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat =  "HH:mm"
dateFormatter.timeZone = .current

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "17:00") {
    datePicker.date = date
}
```

Please help me to default to time 5:00PM always. Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem ? what shows ?

Comment: Start by understanding/spotting the issue. What's the value of `date`? It's (on my timezone): `2000-01-01 16:00:00 +0000`, you see the year, month, day? Were they the one you think of? Are you looking on getting 17h00, but on current day, on specific day? Then, look how to do so.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is to get the current date and set hour, minute and second accordingly

```
let fivePM = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 17, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())!
datePicker.date = fivePM
```

Another way is to set the `countDownDuration` property

```
datePicker.countDownDuration = 61200 // 17 * 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer would be:

```swift
let cal = Calendar.current
let timeZone: TimeZone = .current

var dateComp = cal.dateComponents(in: timeZone, from: Date())
(dateComp.hour, dateComp.minute, dateComp.second, dateComp.nanosecond) = (17, 0, 0, 0)

let fivePM = cal.date(from: dateComp)
datePicker.date = fivePM
```

Using this technique you can also get 5pm of the time of another timezone.

Notice that when debugging in Xcode, Xcode will show all dates in the console in the GMT timezone.